# Structured variable replacement not working for web.config (XML)

Tags: octopus-deploy, octopus

Octopus Server 2021.1

I’m attempting to use the structured variable replacement feature to replace parts of a web.config (XML) file, but it only tries to read the read the file as Json and Yaml but not Xml. The variable is called the following: /configuration/system.webServer/rewrite/rules/rule/action/@url, where @url is the attribute of the element.
I have tried many things but cant seem to get it to treat the web.config file as an XML file - does anyone have experience getting this type of substitution to work in Octopus Deploy?

The code in the web.config looks like this:

> ```
>   <system.webServer>
>     <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false" />
>     <rewrite>
>       <rules>
>         <rule name="ReverseProxyInboundRule1" stopProcessing="true">
>           <match url="^api/(.*)" />
>           <action type="Rewrite" url="http://localhost:8053/api/{R:1}" appendQueryString="true" />
>         </rule>
>       </rules>
>     </rewrite>
>   </system.webServer>
> ```

> ```
> ||15:22:17   Verbose  |       The file at C:\Octopus\Work\20210612032325-158854-2674\staging\Web.config does not match any known filename patterns. The file will be tried as multiple formats and will be treated as the first format that can be successfully parsed.|
> |---|---|
> ||15:22:17   Verbose  |       Attempting structured variable replacement on file C:\Octopus\Work\20210612032325-158854-2674\staging\Web.config with format Json|
> ||15:22:17   Verbose  |       The file at C:\Octopus\Work\20210612032325-158854-2674\staging\Web.config couldn't be parsed as Json: Unexpected character encountered while parsing value: <. Path '', line 0, position 0.|
> ||15:22:17   Verbose  |       Attempting structured variable replacement on file C:\Octopus\Work\20210612032325-158854-2674\staging\Web.config with format Yaml|
> ||15:22:17   Info     |       No structures have been found that match variable names, so no structured variable replacements have been applied.|
> ||15:22:17   Info     |       Structured variable replacement succeeded on file C:\Octopus\Work\20210612032325-158854-2674\staging\Web.config with format Yaml|
> ||15:22:17   Verbose  |       The file at C:\Octopus\Work\20210612032325-158854-2674\staging\Views\Web.config does not match any known filename patterns. The file will be tried as multiple formats and will be treated as the first format that can be successfully parsed.|
> ||15:22:17   Verbose  |       Attempting structured variable replacement on file C:\Octopus\Work\20210612032325-158854-2674\staging\Views\Web.config with format Json|
> ||15:22:17   Verbose  |       The file at C:\Octopus\Work\20210612032325-158854-2674\staging\Views\Web.config couldn't be parsed as Json: Unexpected character encountered while parsing value: <. Path '', line 0, position 0.|
> ||15:22:17   Verbose  |       Attempting structured variable replacement on file C:\Octopus\Work\20210612032325-158854-2674\staging\Views\Web.config with format Yaml|
> ||15:22:17   Info     |       No structures have been found that match variable names, so no structured variable replacements have been applied.|
> ||15:22:17   Info     |       Structured variable replacement succeeded on file C:\Octopus\Work\20210612032325-158854-2674\staging\Views\Web.config with format Yaml|
> ```

Comment: As mentioned by @ryan.rousseau below, it was in fact a bug and Octopus are working on a fix in a future release. It is limited only to deploying to Azure App Services.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should be working based on the [docs](https://octopus.com/docs/projects/steps/configuration-features/structured-configuration-variables-feature#how-the-file-type-for-target-files-is-determined).

It could be a bug. The best action now is to email support@octopus.com with the details and full log file for diagnosis.

With .NET config files, there is an alternate pattern you can use to get the same result detailed in the [docs](https://octopus.com/docs/projects/steps/configuration-features/configuration-transforms/environment-specific-transforms-with-sensitive-values#one-transform-and-variable-replacement) that involves combining a config file transform and substitute variable templates in files.